# Ошибка Icacls 'Invalid parameter "%Username%"' при попытке дать права текущему пользователю

Tags: windows-10, powershell

Из этого ответа на вопрос [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1470382) to question [Windows SSH: Permissions for 'private-key' are too open][1] я узнал о команде

```
Icacls "C:\Users\XX\Path\To\File" /Grant:r "%Username%":"(R)"
```

но в моей среде это не работает:

```
Invalid parameter "%Username%"
```

Разумеется, я ищу лёгкое но технические правильное решение этой проблемы, но мне также нужно знать, почему конкретно у меня эта ошибка возникла.

Кстати говоря, это немного офф-топ, но настораживает, что несмотря на сброс прав через

```
Icacls "C:\Users\XX\Path\To\File" /Inheritance:r
```

при попытке копировать ключи на VPS

```
ssh -i "C:\Users\XX\Path\To\File" non_root_admin@XXX.XXX.XX.XXX
```

всё равно возникает та самая **WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!**, который меня и привёл к этому вопросу. Но если этот факт не содержит никакой полезной для текущей темы, то я, как и обязан, обсужу её отдельным вопросом.
[1]: https://superuser.com/q/1296024

Comment: вы ж используете powershell: попробуйте `$Username` (или я что-то путаю)

Comment: @return На этот раз Icacls-команда завершилась без ошибки! Ошибка "WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!" пока не исчезла, но проблема данного вопроса решена. Могу ли я Вас попросить оформить Ваш комментарий в качестве ответа с минимальными пояснениями? Я зачту Ваш замечательный ответ и дам Вам очки репутации.

Comment: вот мой ответ: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-7.2