# "WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!" - не получается войти в учётную записать VPS по ключам с локальной Windows-машины

Tags: windows-10, ssh, powershell, vps, ssh-key

Руководствуясь [статьёй из авторитетного источника](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys-on-ubuntu-20-04-ru), изготовил пару ключей для входа на VPS и скопировал их (правда, в статье, не написано, как это делать в Windows, но я эту проблему решил).

Теперь, когда я пытаюсь зайти на VPS через SSH

```
ssh -i "C:\Users\Me\.ssh\MyWebApp.pub" non_root_admin@160.XXX.XX.XXX
```

я получаю предупреждение

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions for 'C:\\Users\\Me\\.ssh\\MyWebApp.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "C:\\Users\\Me\\.ssh\\MyWebApp.pub": bad permissions
non_root_admin@160.XXX.XX.XXX's password:
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже на этом этапе возникает два вопроса:

1. Ключ создан в папке пользователя (скажем, **Me**). Как это так он "доступен другим" (accessible by others)?
2. В заголовке сказано, что незащищён приватный ключ, а **.pub** - это вроде как публичный.

Буду благодарен за объяснение этих моментов, а пока я приведу попытку решения проблемы.

На [Stack Exchange](https://superuser.com/a/1470382) я нагуглил PowerShell решение:

```
Icacls <file name> /Inheritance:r
Icacls <file name> /Grant:r "%Username%":"(R)"
```

Насколько я понял, его идея - запретить все взаимодействия с файлом для всех пользователей и затем разрешить чтение для текущего.

Во-первых, если попытаться ввести вторую команду, то будет ошибка, которой я посвятил [отдельный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1387595/193415). В общем, правильно будет так:

```
Icacls <file name> /Grant:r "$Username":"(R)"
```

По завершению операции PowerShell скажет, что всё завершилось удачно, но если попробовать зайти в учётную запись, будет то же самое предупреждение.

Пробовал повторить те же действия для приватного ключа - не помогло.

Также попрошу не рекомендовать мне в этом вопросе перейти на MacOS и Linux, так как данный вопрос сфокусирован именно Windows, да и по поисковым запросам сюда тоже будут приходить пользователи Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны не пытаться установить права для пользователя, а наоборот оставить права на эти файлы только этому пользователю, а у остальных пользователей прав на эти файлы быть не должно.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Подскажите пожалуйста, а команда в этом случае какая должна быть?

Comment: Права должны быть 600. В линуксе эта команда выглядит так ```chmod 600 path_to_file```